# How to change the HTML DOM elements spawning position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, dom

I'm making a web page that allows the users to add their interests. I'm planning to send the input data to a WebAPI later. 
I used Javascript DOM to spawn new Buttons for every Text Input. Then I added it in a form.
The function works fine but the issue is the new Buttons that spawn are spawning outside the Div I wanted them to spawn in.

Here is a screenshot of it.
[Screenshot of the Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18RCI.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>IPT - Student Register</title>
<meta name="description" content="IPT - NSBM">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-icon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/selectFX/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
<div class="sufee-login d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-content">
            <div class="login-logo">
                <p>IPT Programme NSBM - NSBM - Student Registration</p>
            </div>
            <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter your Qualifications</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myText" value=Qualification 1">
                            <br>
                            <button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
                            <br>   
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var y = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
      x.setAttribute("type", "button");
      x.setAttribute("value", y);
      document.body.appendChild(x);  
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way that I can spawn those buttons in the White color  itself? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the issue be that you appended the buttons to the websites body in your JavaScript rather then the flex container div class you have? Maybe you should try creating the buttons strictly in the flex div and then add their functionality in JavaScript. Hope this helps, and good luck :)

Comment: Also it’s difficult to tell 100% without seeing your CSS. If answer doesn’t fix it, you should post your CSS.

Comment: Oh my god it worked!!! :D Thank you so much Jen. I'm more familiar with native app development and flutter. And I'm really bad at Javascript. Thank you so much again! :)